# Is there a way to track the volume of a disk traffic from/to a particular file

Tags: hard-drive, qemu, io

I'm running a VM (qemu) that has its virtual disk on my hard drive. It works pretty slow so I'm thinking of moving that virtual disk to SSD. The only thing I am concerned about is whether it would be harmful for SSD or impact SSD lifetime.

Ideally I would like to measure IO traffic coming through that virtual disk file on some time extent so that I can reliably estimate how harmful r/w of my VM would be for my SSD.

Is there a tool or a method that I could use for that purpose?

Answer (score 1):

you can run

```
  # identify the disk you care for
  $ virsh domblklist <guest>
   Target   Source
  -------------------------------------------------------------
   vda      /var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images/focal.qcow
   vdb      /var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images/focal-ds.qcow
  # Then monitor it via
  $ virsh domblkstat <guestname> <disk>
  vda rd_req 23209
  vda rd_bytes 913245696
  vda wr_req 60929
  vda wr_bytes 2483832832
  vda flush_operations 52825
  vda rd_total_times 3619008820
  vda wr_total_times 43149173909
  vda flush_total_times 30698076825
```

This isn't perfect, but is the virt-stacks view of what is going on and should give you enough for an estimate what to expect.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try.